# How can I upgrade a sub-panel without upgrading the three-conductor supply?

Tags: electrical

I have a sub panel in my detached garage. I wanted to change the sub panel. I found that it is a 3 wire feed, neutral, and 2 hot, no ground. The panel is connected to the metal conduit coming in from the floor, but the conduit ends  when it reaches the basement in the house about 60’ away. It does not connect to the main panel. It doesn’t seem to be properly grounded.

How can I change the panel properly with out pulling a new 4 wire to the garage from the main?

Comment: Any reason you can't just pull a new ground wire?

Comment: What type of wire from the sub panel to the main panel?  From where the conduit ends to the sub panel?

Comment: Pulling a new ground would be easy but I have no way concealing it unless I dig up the black top or doing an over head.

Comment: In the conduit looks like URD and from the conduit to the main looks like a SER

Comment: Do you have access to both ends of the conduit? It's unclear from your post since your comments say you would have to dig up blacktop.

Comment: If you have access to the end of the conduit in your basement, you can use a conduit ground clamp to attach a ground wire there, and run that wire back to your panel.  Metal conduit is a valid grounding path, and it will take the ground connection the rest of the way to your subpanel.

Comment: I would use the conduit as a conductor as Nate mentioned. It is also legal to pull in a new ground wire separately from your other wiring method. Nate I would make that an answer+

Comment: Do you have a path to run a ground wire from that conduit end to your main panel, or to some point on your grounding electrode system for that matter?

Comment: Also, what size is the conduit, and what gauge are the existing wires inside it?  Furthermore, are you certain the conduit is continuous from the basement to the garage?

Comment: Using the conduit would be perfect! I’m guessing it’s continuous, what I do know, because of some digging next to the garage, it makes at least one 90 about two feet out from the garage.  But I have no way of knowing the integrity conduit under ground if it is continuous, it looks perfect at each end

Comment: As for sizing the conduit is 11/2” and the wire is #2

Comment: What size breaker protects this feeder? Does the SER cable indoors have 3 wires or 4?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your conduit is continuous from your basement to your subpanel, your best option is to use it as your ground path.  Metal conduit is an excellent ground conductor, and can easily handle hundreds of amps, even when a little rusty.

Buy a conduit ground clamp, such as [this one:](https://www.homedepot.com/p/NSi-Industries-Heavy-Duty-Direct-Burial-Bronze-Ground-Clamp-for-1-25-in-to-2-in-Pipe-G-2-SDB/307267843)

[image: Conduit Ground Clamp]
(Image courtesy of Home Depot)

Then, run an [appropriately sized](http://wiresizecalculator.net/tables/groundconductortable.htm) green or bare copper wire from the end of the conduit in your basement to your service panel, or any point along your grounding electrode system.  This will complete the ground path from your subpanel back to your main panel.

Now, to complete the conversion, shut off the breaker feeding your subpanel, and remove the neutral-ground bond that's likely in there.  This may require moving neutral and ground wires onto separate buses if they're currently mixed.

If you're not sure the conduit is continuous (i.e. it might transition to plasitc somewhere underground), you can now test that with a multimeter and an extension cord:  Plug it into any regular outlet in the house, walk to the subpanel in the garage, and test for continuity between the round ground pin of that extension cord and the metal conduit going into your subpanel.  If it has continuity, you're good to go.  If not, now pull another ground wire through the conduit and connect it at the subpanel and main panel/grounding electrode system (but still leave the conduit clamp connected as well -- it's good to bond conduit to ground even if it isn't serving as a ground path).

Comment: It's important to ensure that there's no ground-neutral bond in the detached garage while testing continuity of the conduit. Might be easiest (meaning, easiest way to get a high-confidence result) to de-power the subpanel, lift its neutral connection, then test resistance between house ground and subpanel box/conduit.

Comment: @GregHill, good point, if it's bonded at both ends, that would show a false positive, so the N-G bond should be removed first.  I'll rearrange my answer to make that clear.